# GIT post-receive on shared path windows

Tags: git

I have problem with hook on git server

My post-receive script is

`#!/bin/bash
git --git-dir=/c/folder/repo/projekt.git --work-tree=/c/folder/repo/projekt/ checkout -f`

and when I'm using it on my remote machine ./postreceive everything is working fine but when I'm pushing something that script is not working there is error

`remote: fatal: Not a git repository: 'C:/folder/repo/projekt.git'
To //192.168.22.10/gitrepo/repo/projekt.git`

gitrepo is my shared path from that remote machine

How can I change post-receive to make it work?

**edit:**

Problem is with pathes (just tried pwd) but I have no idea how to solve it?

**edit2:**
Changed the hook post-receive work_tree_path on =../projekt and that thing is working fine now but I have still no idea why script from server is using path from LOCAL MACHINE to use it on REMOTE MACHINE

Comment: Use `cd` to change the current working directory?

Comment: Can you explain your solution?
When I tried `cd` and checked out `ls` there was folders from my local machine and I'm not sure what I have change in post-receive to use remote machine path instead of client

Comment: using relative paths is a good workaround, been struggling for 3h to make it work with windows style c:\something\something nonsense ;-)